# need help coverting string to type number(20,3)

Tags: java, string, double

I have a field name varaince in a table set to type Number(20,3) in oracle.....
I get number as string from the webpage and convert it to Double so I can write it back to table as shown below

```
if ( (this.getVariance() != null) && (this.getVariance().length() > 0) )
                cstmt.setDouble(7,Util.stringToDouble(this.getVariance()));
            else
                cstmt.setNull(7,OracleTypes.NUMBER);
```

but i am getting this error

```
compile:
     [exec] com\sample\common\javabean\ExampleBean.java:261: cannot resolve symbol
     [exec] symbol  : method setDouble (int,java.lang.Double)
     [exec] location: interface java.sql.CallableStatement
     [exec]                             cstmt.setDouble(7,Util.stringToDouble(this.getVariance()));
     [exec]           

                       ^
```

when i was doing samething as integer it didnt give me error but it didnt write to table.

What can be done to convert string in such a way that table will write that number from the form. Any help would be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to convert it to a double? You could do this:

```
cstmt.setBigDecimal(7, new java.math.BigDecimal(this.getVariance()));
```

Comment: i tried this way but its setting it to null rather than number that i put in

Answer (score 1):

Change `Util.stringToDouble(this.getVariance())` to `Util.stringToDouble(this.getVariance()).doubleValue()`.

**details...**

`stringToDouble` seems to be returning a `java.lang.Double` object. This means it is returning a reference to an object that actually carries the double on it. This is useful for anything that requires an `Object` because `Double` is an `Object`.

`doubleValue` returns a `double` (lowercase). With this format, the actual 8 byte number is returned. This is more efficient because it does not require object allocation, but does not work when an `Object` is required. However, in this case, the performance impact has done its damage because you are using `stringToDouble`. You may consider using `Double.parseDouble(...)` instead of `Util.stringToDouble(...).doubleValue()`

Comment: it worked but its setting null as the value rather than the number i put it in

Comment: Try setting a hard coded value like `40.5`. (`cstmt.setDouble(7, 40.5)`)

Comment: even hardcoded is setting to null.. do you know what might be the cause for that

Comment: found the error.. it was at other place... i was having value passing error.. thank you for your help